# Which Salesforce editions support <apex:map> tag?

Tags: visualforce

I know that `apex:map` tag doesn't work in Developer Edition but I assumed it is working in my client's Group Edition.
To my great surprize, `apex:map` tag isn't available in Group Edition but this is not even documented.

Is there any explicit list of editions which support `apex:map`?

Comment: Developer docs explicitly says only dev edition is unsupported and quick question, Did you [enable creation of Visualforce maps ?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_maps.htm&type=5)

Comment: Yeah that seems like the obvious answer.

Comment: So I would like to enable creation of visualforce maps, but unfortunately, it is not available and Apex:map tag documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_map.htm  doesn't say anything about the editions this tag in supported in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, looks like I didn't notice before, but know I see that [documentation states that Map and Location Services can be enabled only in the following editions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_maps.htm&type=5):

- Professional
- Enterprise
- Performance
- Unlimited

[image]

So, unfortunately, it is not available in Developer, Group Edition, other editions like Essentials.

Answer (score 2):

Like I mentioned in the comments Developer docs explicitly mentions that

> Visualforce mapping components aren’t available in Developer Edition
>   organizations.

Other than that for other editions to use mapping components in Visualforce Page you need to [enable visualforce maps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_maps.htm&type=5) by enabling your organization’s map and location services

Comment: My client has "Group edition", when I go to Quick Find from Setup and enter Map, it doesn't give me any results. So looks like documentation is wrong. There is no way to enabled maps in Group Edition.

Comment: @Patlatus Funny It slipped through my eye too! I'm glad you found it!